# How to group items in dynamic array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here is simple Javascript problem. I have two arrays fruits and basket. Basket is always sorted.

```
var fruits = [''];
var basket = ["Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange"];
```

I want each element of basket to be grouped like this.

```
Apple
I have Apple
I have Apple

Banana
I have Banana

Orange
I have Orange
I have Orange
I have Orange
```

Code
    HTML

```
<div id="table"></div>
```

Code JS

```
var fruits = [''];
var basket = ["Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange"];

for (var i = 0; i < basket.length; i++) { 
  var fruit = basket[i];

  for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++) {
    if (fruit == fruits[j]) {
      // Existing fruit
      $("#table").append("I have " + fruit);
      break;
    } else {
      // New fruit
      $("#table").append("<h1>" + fruit + "</h1>");
      $("#table").append("I have " + fruit);
      fruits.push(fruit);
      break;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work. It ends up looking like this. How do I fix? Fruits inside basket could be different so this should be dynamic.

```
Apple
I have Apple

Apple
I have Apple

Banana
I have Banana

Orange
I have Orange

Orange
I have Orange

Orange
I have Orange
```

Comment: So I guess `basket` isn't **always sorted** then ?

Comment: It is always sorted

Comment: @adeneo it could be  var basket = ["Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Dragonfruit"];

Comment: So could you use a Dictionary instead then? Where fruits are made up of arrays of those who own the fruit? ` { Orange: [], ... }`

Comment: @axlj basket is dynamic so could be different everytime containing different fruits

Comment: @KevinB - sure, but in your code the `basket` array isn't sorted alpabetically, `orange` comes before `banana`, but it seems you want `banana` to come first anyway, otherwise it does exactly what's expected -> https://jsfiddle.net/bkocbf2t/

Comment: Anyway, just call `basket.sort()` before the loop

Comment: @adeneo ah that is a typo

Comment: It is always sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is sorted, it would be easy to save aside the last "groupName" and print it when encountered with a new group for the first time.
If it not sorted call `.sort` before that.

```js
var basket = ["Apple", "Apple", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Banana"];

let lastGroup = '';
for (var i = 0; i < basket.length; i++) {
  var fruit = basket[i];

  if (lastGroup !== fruit) {
    lastGroup = fruit;
    $("#table").append("<h1>" + fruit + "</h1>");
  }
  $("#table").append("I have " + fruit + "\n");
}
```

```css
div {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: This is first answer and straight forward. Will accept, can you tell me why my original code did not work

Comment: Hamm, the second loop is redundant, you can "collect" the visited fruit with the array of visited fruits, and then check if you "visited" a fruit using `fruits.indexOf(fruit) > -1`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the array method [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). The way reduce works is it applies a function to an accumulator and every item in an array, so essentially its purpose is to “reduce” an array into a single object.

```
var arr = ["Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange"];
var groupedElements = arr.reduce(function(groups, item) {
    groups[item] = groups[item] || 0;
    groups[item]++;
    return groups;
  }, {});

console.log(groupedElements);
//is {Apple: 2, Banana: 1, Orange: 3}
```

Printing out should be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `fruits` to an object that keeps count, you can do

```js
var fruits = {};
var basket = ["Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange"];

$.each(basket, (_,fruit) => fruit in fruits ? fruits[fruit]++ : fruits[fruit] = 1);
$.each(fruits, (k,v) => {
  $("#table").append("<h1>" + k + "</h1>");
  $.each(Array(v).fill(0), () => $("#table").append("<p>I have " + k + "</p>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: This works. Upvoted. However why my original code not work?

Comment: It doesn't work because you iterate over the same thing, creating the same header each time

Comment: so the outer for loop should iterate over fruits and not basket

Answer (score 0):

How about this, just change the console.log lines to append your html:

```
var basket = ["Apple", "Apple", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange", "Banana"];

for (var i = 0; i < basket.length; i++) { 
  if (basket[i] == basket[i-1]) {
    continue;
  }  
  console.log(basket[i])

  j = i;
  while (basket[i] === basket[j]) {
    console.log(`I have ${basket[i]}`);
    j++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume one of the way to resolve the issue is to create a object from the array of basket. The object can have fruit name as key and number of fruit as value.

Then using `for..in` the result can be appended to the table

```js
var fruits = [''];
var basket = ["Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange"];
var fruitObject = {}

basket.forEach(function(item) {
  if (fruitObject.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    fruitObject[item] = fruitObject[item] + 1

  } else {
    fruitObject[item] = 1;

  }
})

for (var keys in fruitObject) {
  $("#table").append("<h1>" + keys + "</h1>");
  for (var i = 0; i < fruitObject[keys]; i++) {
    $("#table").append("I have " + keys + '<br/>');

  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to use `if (fruits.indexOf(fruit) !== -1)` instead of a for-loop, to check if fruit exist in array or not:

```js
var fruits = [''];
var basket = ["Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange"];

for (i in basket) { 
    var fruit = basket[i];
    if (fruits.indexOf(fruit) !== -1) {
        // Existing fruit
        $("#table").append("I have " + fruit);
    } else {
        // New fruit
        $("#table").append("<h1>" + fruit + "</h1>");
        $("#table").append("I have " + fruit);
        fruits.push(fruit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem with your code:**

The problem happens when you enter the inner loop. That loop doesn't search it just compares the first element of the array `fruits` with the current `fruit` from the `basket` array. Due to the existing `break` statement inside both `if` and `else` the loop only iterates over the first element and terminates. Hence the loop is useless and your code is equvalent to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < basket.length; i++) { 
  var fruit = basket[i];

  var j = 0;
  if (fruit == fruits[j]) {
      $("#table").append("I have " + fruit);
  } else {
      $("#table").append("<h1>" + fruit + "</h1>");
      $("#table").append("I have " + fruit);
      fruits.push(fruit);
  }
}
```

Since `fruits[0] === ''` the else statement will be executed for all the fruits as they are all `!= ''`. If you remove the empty string from `fruits` array, then only `Apple` will show up right as both `Banana` and `Orange` are `!= "Apple"`.

**What should be done to fix your code:**

You must loop through the `fruits` array to see if the current fruit exists or not before executing any code (the code inside `if` and `else`). Or you can use a search function such as `indexOf` to simpliy the code.

**Suggested solution:**

If the array is sorted, then just use while to show the `"I have ..."`s before appending the next `h1` element.

```js
var basket = ["Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange", "Orange"];

for(var i = 0; i < basket.length; i--) {
  var fruit = basket[i];                                      // the current fruit
  $("#table").append("<h1>" + fruit + "</h1>");               // append a title element
  while(basket[i++] === fruit)                                // while the next fruits are the same:
    $("#table").append("<div>I have " + fruit + "</div>");    // append the "I have ..." text
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

**Notice** that the `for` loop decrements `i` instead of incrementing it. That's because the while is actually responsible for the incrementing, and when a new fruit is encountered, `i` should go back one step (which the `for` loop does for us).

Answer (score 0):

Don't append markup to the DOM in a loop (unless it's inevitable). Build the whole markup first and then add it at once

```js
var basket = ["Orange", "Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];

//generate the markup first, ...
var markup = basket
  //don't mutate the original Array
  .slice().sort()
  //generate the markup for each item in the sorted basket
  .map(function(fruit, index, array) {
    //check wether it's a new group
    var title = (!index || fruit !== array[index - 1]) ?
      "<h1>" + fruit + "</h1>\n" :
      "";
    //just for fun
    var article = /^[aeiou]/i.test(fruit) ? "an" : "a";

    //return the whole markup for this row
    return title + "I have " + article + " " + fruit + "\n";
  })
  .join("")

//... then append the whole markup at once
$("#table").append(markup);
```

```css
#table {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

or alternatively count how often each fruit appears and then build the rows based on that:

```js
var basket = ["Orange", "Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];

var countFruits = Object.create(null);

basket.forEach(function(fruit) {
  if (fruit in countFruits) {
    countFruits[fruit]++;
  } else {
    countFruits[fruit] = 1;
  }
});

//generate the markup first, ...
var markup = Object.keys(countFruits).map(function(fruit) {
  var title = "<h1>" + fruit + "</h1>";
  var article = /^[aeiou]/i.test(fruit) ? "an" : "a";
  var row = "I have " + article + " " + fruit + "\n";
  return title + row.repeat(countFruits[fruit]);
}).join("");

//... then append the whole markup at once
$("#table").append(markup);
```

```css
#table {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

The second example keeps the groups in the order of their first appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I see two bugs in your code:

First one is this: `var fruits = [''];` you created array where first element is an empty string. In the loop `for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++)` you always compare fruit from basket with empty string (and think it is new fruit) and then break from that for loop.

When you break, next fruit in the basket is again compared with empty string (again considered to be new). You never get to compare fruit from the basket with any element from fruits array past index 0.

And at index 0 you have empty string.

If you change `var fruits = [''];` to `var fruits = [];` thing will not work again, since for loop in which you are displaying fruits will never run.

Any way, console.log is your friend. If you put this lines

```
console.log('fruit=' + fruit, 'j=' + j, 'fruits[j]=' + fruits[j]);
console.log('fruits=', fruits);
```

just after `for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++) {` everything will be clear:

```
fruit=Apple j=0 fruits[j]=  
fruits= Array [ "" ]  
fruit=Apple j=0 fruits[j]=  
fruits= Array [ "", "Apple" ]  
fruit=Banana j=0 fruits[j]=  
fruits= Array [ "", "Apple", "Apple" ]  
fruit=Orange j=0 fruits[j]=  
fruits= Array [ "", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana" ]  
fruit=Orange j=0 fruits[j]=  
fruits= Array [ "", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange" ]  
fruit=Orange j=0 fruits[j]=  
fruits= Array [ "", "Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange" ]
```

I will not post correct code since many others already posted the working version.